# Can i use a pci express 1.0 card in a pci express 2.0 x16 slot?

Tags: sata, pci

I am runing out of sata connections and need to expand using a pci card, however, i only have a pci express 2.0 slot available, will a pcie 1.0 (pci express 1.0) expansion card work in a pci express 2.0 slot?

Comment: I have a PCIe 2.0 card in a PCIe 1.0 slot and it works fine.  So, the slot - by that example - is *forwards compatible*: newer cards work in older slots.  I don't see any reason why not that they aren't *backwards compatible* as well: older cards work in newer slots.  You may not be able to get the maximum performance you could have out of the combination but it should still work.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR;  Yes, you can.

Slightly longer:

PCI express is backward compatible. You can run a PCI-e version 1 device is a PCI-e version 2 slot. You will only get PCI-e version 1 speeds though (which is up to 2.5 megabit per lane).

As to the X16: 
You can run any card in any slot into which it fits.  It will use the maximum available combination of lanes.

Answer (score 0):

It depends from your host: the compatibility is not really complete. For example, I tried an old network card on a DELL PowerEdge T30, but it did not work. Finally I found the problem was at the PCIe level. The user manual of T30 states *NOTE: All the PCIe slots support Generation 2 and 3 PCIe expansion cards*. As you see, there is no mention of PCIe 1.0 nor 1.1.

And, in my case, the network card box only mentioned *require a PCIe compatible bus*. I had to look for the chipset datasheet in order to find the PCIe version required.